# аналог addShutdownHook

Tags: php

**Задача:**
Есть форма добавления изображений, файлов, текстов.
Когда заполняем форму и отправляем, сначала загружаются изображения, файлы, а только потом записываются текста.

**Вопрос:**
Как мне сделать так, чтобы когда идет загрузка изображений и файлов и если вдруг мы закрыли браузер, дома выключили свет, закрыли вкладку или еще чего.
Нужно, чтобы эти самые изображения и файлы удалились, которые уже загрузились, к примеру загрузилась картинка, осталось загрузить 2 картинки и 2 файла и резко закрыли вкладку.
Дело в том, что - та картинка, которая загрузилась в определенную папку, она остается и уже некорректная папка, так как форма вся не обработалась, не успела.

К примеру в java мы можем это сделать через:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Shutdown());
```

То есть если программа некорректно закрыта, мы можем через `addShutdownHook` обработать все необходимое для завершения программы, чтобы она открылась корректно.

Как такое сделать в `php`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Существует [register_shutdown_function](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.register-shutdown-function.php), но, как и в случае с shutdown hook, это грязный метод.

Проще по крону раз в сутки находить лишние файлы и прибивать их.

Comment: Смотрел не раз в сторону `register_shutdown_function` - но сначала не правильно понял принцип ее работы, а она работает по аналогии `addShutdownHook`, просто php сразу умирает после обработки скрипта - это не учел (забыл), но собственно проблема решена, добавил условие на некорректную папку и т.д. и все идеально отрабатывает и сносит если некорректно.